# Is there a way to determine which lines of code actually ran in a production environment?

Tags: go, code-coverage

Is there a way to determine which lines of code actually ran in a production environment?
Like code coverage, but not in tests. In real code execution.

To determine dead code

Comment: https://go.dev/blog/integration-test-coverage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In go 1.20 we can use flag -cover

```
go build -cover
```

And then just run app

```
GOCOVERDIR=somedata ./myapp
```

In the directory the stats will be collected. It can be transformed to regular text format

```
go tool covdata textfmt -i=somedata -o coverage.txt
```

After that you can look at the result:

```
go tool cover -html=coverage.txt
```

Comment: More info in https://go.dev/testing/coverage/#running

Comment: I wasn't able to find reference on this, but from a conference I was on there was a note that building with `-cover` flag incurs performance penalties. So be careful when using it in production environment.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such way that I know of. But, you could emit metrics in the parts that you consider dead and if you get 0 datapoints for a significant period of time, you could be pretty confident that the code isn't being used.

Comment: This worked nicely for us. We already had monitoring in place, so it was very easy to add it. Added benefit is that you can add data to metrics so you can have more information surrounding line execution.